# merge aggregation and find results in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this model:

```
const recordSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Person',
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  },
  time: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});
```

So, when I make a HTTP Get request I receive an array of records:

`[{/*record1*/}, {/*record2*/}, ...]`

The point is that I'm using aggregation to get the number of records of each user (I got that cover), but I would like merge this with the find results to receive something like this:

```
{
  "records": [{/*record1*/}, {/*record2*/}, ...],
  "stats": [
    { 
      "_id" : ObjectId("5b6393f2a1d3de31d9547f63"),
      "count" : 3.0
    },
    { 
      "_id" : ObjectId("5b5d22d8b6195d1b6a5d2574"),
      "count" : 17.0
    }
  ]
}
```

So, how do I get this?

**Note**: I'm using this for data for some charts, should I handle this on node or on the front-end?

Comment: What's your MongoDB Server version?

Comment: I have version 3.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in the back-end and if you're using MongoDB Server version 3.4.4 or greater in your backend, **[`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)** aggregate pipeline should cover your needs.

Consider the following example which runs two aggregate queries in the same aggregate pipeline using **[`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)**: one returns the records for today and the other returns the counts for each user in the collection:

```
let start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

let end = new Date();
end.setHours(23,59,59,999);

Record.aggregate([
    { '$facet': {
        'records': [
            { '$match': { 
                'date': {
                    '$gte': start,
                    '$lte': end
                }
            } }
        ],
        'stats': [
            { '$group': { 
                '_id': '$user',
                'count': { '$sum': 1 }
            } }
        ]
    } }
]).exec((err, results) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw new Error(err);
    }

    const data = results[0];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
})
```

---

### For MongoDB 3.2 and below

**1. Using Promises**

```
const recordsQuery = Record.find({ 'date': {
    '$gte': start, // date object representing start of today
    '$lte': end    // date object representing end of today
} }).lean().exec();

const statsQuery = Record.aggregate([
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': '$user',
        'count': { '$sum': 1 }
    } }
]).exec();

Promise.all([ recordsQuery, statsQuery ]).then(([ recordsData, statsData ]) => {
    const records = recordsData[0];
    const stats = statsData[0];

    const data = { records, stats };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**2. Using async/await**

```
(async () =>  {
    try {
        const recordsQuery = await Record.find({ 'date': {
            '$gte': start, // date object representing start of today
            '$lte': end    // date object representing end of today
        } }).lean().exec();

        const statsQuery = await Record.aggregate([
            { '$group': { 
                '_id': '$user',
                'count': { '$sum': 1 }
            } }
        ]).exec();

        const records = recordsQuery[0];
        const stats = statsQuery[0];

        const data = { records, stats };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator to link the original records for the users by Id

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```